# truffle init not working

Tags: truffle, nodejs

I am trying to run "truffle init" in the empty directory, facing the following error.

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:26041
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                                        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

Can someone please help? thanks in advance!

[EDIT]
After running "npm install -g truffle@latest" , got the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:79
  let notifier = require('update-notifier')({pkg})
      ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

Comment: What is your node version? You probably are using an old version try upgrading to at least node v8

Comment: $ node --version
v0.10.25

Comment: That is a really old version. If you are on Windows or Mac download the more recent binaries from https://nodejs.org/en/download/, if you are on Linux try using your package manager and follow instructions from here https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

Answer (score 2):

Use node version manager(nvm) to install the latest stable node js version.
https://github.com/creationix/nvm
The most recent stable version is **10.15.1**

After that, Run the same command to not see the error.